# Catch-all or error routes in Sammy.js

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

Is it possible to define a catch-all route or an error route in Sammy.js? I know I can bind to 'error' but if no route matches that does not seem to be triggered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation for Sammy routes](http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/docs/routes.html),

> Paths can be defined as strings or
>   regular expressions.

As such, it should be possible to create a route like this, at the end of your routes, that is a catch-all:

```
get(/.*/, function() { 
  ...
});
```

Comment: minor point - take note of the lack of quotes, this is a literal regular expression.   '/.*/' is quite different than /.*/

Comment: One problem with this approach is that your route will catch even the links that would navigate away from your page. You probably don't want that.

Comment: In my testing with a single page application, this worked and did not trigger when navigating to another page.

Answer (score 24):

You should override the `notFound` function.

Like this:

```
var app = $.sammy('#app', function() {
  this.notFound = function(){
    // do something
  }
});
```

This is [recommended](https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/issues/67) by the author of Sammy.

Comment: This is appropriate for implementing a 404 Not Found event, but as a catch-all route it's not so practical because `this` will be the `Application`, and not an `EventContext`. So there won't be properties like `path` and `params`.